# Ошибка при прохождении сертификата Windows Store

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, windows-phone-8, microsoft-store

В общем, пытаюсь сделать appx файл через VS. После компиляции пытаюсь пройти сертификацию, валится на таком:

```
Проверка конфигурации отладки

ОШИБКА
Конфигурация отладки
Обнаружена ошибка: При тестировании конфигурации отладки обнаружены следующие ошибки:
Построение двоичного файла FFF.exe выполнено в режиме отладки.
Последствия, если проблема не устранена: Магазин Windows Phone не разрешает отлаженные версии приложений.
Инструкции по исправлению: Убедитесь, что приложение не связано с отлаженными версиями платформы и создано на основе конфигурации выпуска.
```

Суть в чем, Release мод стоит:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что вообще VS хочет от меня?

Comment: Вероятно, вы в Windows Store подсунули файл предыдущей версии, собранный ещё в Debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, проблема была в том что в одном из двух проектов не была выставлена галочка: `Optimize code`. [Пруф на English SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933739/what-is-the-difference-between-release-and-debug-modes-in-visual-studio).